# Store custom files on heroku postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, postgresql-9.5, heroku-postgres, unaccent

I am trying to create custom rules for the builtin function `unaccent` on postgres. [Postgres' documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/unaccent.html) states `This file must be stored in $SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/ (where $SHAREDIR means the PostgreSQL installation's shared-data directory). Its name must end in .rules (which is not to be included in the RULES parameter)`. It is easy to create on my local data base but I am wondering, how can I do it on heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to upload supporting files to the fs on the database host for Heroku Postgres. Heroku Postgres simply does not support this level of custom configuration. They take care of the vast majority of ops on your behalf but it does limit what they can reasonably allow users to change on the system.

Comment: And this isn't unique to Heroku Postgres. Most hosted PostgreSQL services won't permit this. If you want that level of control, administer your own instance on a VPS or something. Alternatively, write a stored procedure instead of using `unaccent`. Stored procedures should work just fine on Heroku Postgres.

Comment: @Chris. I am thinking about writing a stored proc as well. Thanks!